# Any possible to print multiple values in single cell using selenium web driver

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For example:

```
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
WebElement points = driver.findElement(By.id("id["+i+"]"));
points.getCssValues("margin-bottom");
}
```

In the above example, margin get have two values. how to print these values in single cell.

Comment: Your question is not clear actually, what do you mean print these values in single cell? Could you share relevant HTML and elaborate more??

Comment: In this code, get margin bottom for two web elements. These two web element's margin have to print in single cell.

Comment: Try as `String margin= "";for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
WebElement points = driver.findElement(By.id("id["+i+"]"));
margin += points.getCssValues("margin-bottom");
} System.out.println(margin);`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this code, get margin bottom for two web elements. These two web element's margin have to print in single cell

You're question is not much clear, but I think you want to get css values from multiple element into single variable and then want to use somewhere.

You need concatenate elements margin css values then print where you want as below :-

```
String margin= "";
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
{ 
  WebElement points = driver.findElement(By.id("id["+i+"]")); 
  margin += points.getCssValues("margin-bottom"); 
} 
System.out.println(margin); // this would print both margin into single
```